# Why is the XSLT count function not working as expected for me?

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT to convert XML to certain file format. I'm excluding reversal transactions matching two fields (OrigTxnId and TxnId). The problem is the count I'm doing in the header for the number of transactions still include the Transactions which have been removed.

Herewith input XML exsample:

```
<XML>
<Record><GroupId>10028</GroupId><Id>1</Id><User>CHRISVI</User><TxnId>264-10028-1-516739-2</TxnId><Date>30-Sep-2014</Date><Time>12:21:24</Time><Account>12440531</Account><Amount>217090</Amount><AllowableMOP>0</AllowableMOP><BankBranchCode>280071</BankBranchCode><ChequeAccNo>62247628681</ChequeAccNo><ChequeNo>000040</ChequeNo></Record>
<Record><GroupId>10028</GroupId><Id>1</Id><User>CHRISVI</User><TxnId>264-10028-1-516743-2</TxnId><Date>30-Sep-2014</Date><Time>12:21:52</Time><Account>10895388</Account><Amount>150000</Amount><AllowableMOP>1</AllowableMOP></Record>
<Record><GroupId>10028</GroupId><Id>1</Id><User>CHRISVI</User><TxnId>264-10028-1-516748-1</TxnId><Date>30-Sep-2014</Date><Time>12:22:26</Time><OrigTxnId>264-10028-1-516743-2</OrigTxnId><Account>10895388</Account><Amount>150000</Amount><AllowableMOP>1</AllowableMOP></Record>
<Record><GroupId>10028</GroupId><Id>1</Id><User>CHRISVI</User><TxnId>264-10028-1-516756-1</TxnId><Date>30-Sep-2014</Date><Time>12:23:01</Time><Account>10895388</Account><Amount>10000</Amount><AllowableMOP>1</AllowableMOP></Record>
<Record><GroupId>10028</GroupId><Id>1</Id><User>CHRISVI</User><TxnId>264-10028-1-516760-2</TxnId><Date>30-Sep-2014</Date><Time>12:23:24</Time><Account>10605762</Account><Amount>15000</Amount><AllowableMOP>1</AllowableMOP></Record>
</XML>
```

The XSLT code to convert XML:

]]>

```
<xsl:key name="original" match="/XML/Record" use="TxnId" />
<xsl:key name="copy" match="/XML/Record" use="OrigTxnId" /> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <?Header Starts?>
    <xsl:value-of select="user:IncrementBatchNo('Batchcow','C:\WebRiposte\Agents\Configuration\Configurations.xml')"/>
    <?RECORDTYPE?>
    <xsl:text>H</xsl:text>
    <?FILETYPE?>
    <xsl:text>PNP</xsl:text>
    <?COMPANYCODE?>
    <xsl:text>WHK</xsl:text>
    <?COMPANYNAME?>
    <xsl:text>                   Windhoek Municipality</xsl:text>
    <?ACTIONDATETIME?>
    <xsl:value-of  select="user:getdatetime()"/>
    <?PAYMENTBATCHNO?>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(user:GetBatchNo('Batchcow','C:\WebRiposte\Agents\Configuration\Configurations.xml'),'000000')"/>
    <?RECORDSIZE?>
    <xsl:text>000256</xsl:text>
    <?NUMRECORDS?>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//SessionId),'000000')"/>
    <?TESTLIVE?>
    <xsl:text>L</xsl:text>
    <?FILLER?>
    <xsl:call-template name="pad-some-space">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentlength" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="newlength" select="177"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <?Line Feed?>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <?Header Ends ?>
    <?Body Starts?>
    <xsl:for-each select="XML/Record[not(key('original', OrigTxnId) or key('copy', TxnId))]">
        <?Record Type - 1 - Fixed value “D”(etail)?>
        <xsl:text>D</xsl:text>
        <?PAYMENTBATCHNO?>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(user:GetBatchNo('Batchcow','C:\WebRiposte\Agents\Configuration\Configurations.xml'),'000000')"/>
        <?SeqNo - 6 - Right justified, zero padded?>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(preceding-sibling::Record)+1, '000000')"/>
        <?CompanyCode - 3 - Leave Blank, Space padded?>
        <xsl:text>WHK</xsl:text>
        <?CustAccountNo - 20 - Right justified, zero padded?>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Account, '00000000000000000000')"/>
        <?Invoice No and Ref no?>
        <xsl:text>0000000000000000000000000</xsl:text>
        <?Create Group id Variable?>
        <xsl:variable name="GroupId" select="GroupId"/>
        <?NamPostBranch - 50 - ?>
        <xsl:call-template name="reformat-string-length">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="user:GetPostOfficeName(string($GroupId),'C:\WebRiposte\Agents\Configuration\Configurations.xml')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="str-len" select="50"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <?NamPostReceiptNo - 16 - Group-Node-Sequence No?>
        <xsl:call-template name="reformat-string-length">
            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring(SessionId,5,16)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="str-len" select="16"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="alignment" select=" 'right' "/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <?MOPCheck?>            
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ChequeNo &gt; 0">
                <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                <?BankBranchCode - 6 - space padded?>
                <xsl:call-template name="reformat-string-length">
                      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="BankBranchCode"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="str-len" select="6"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>                
                <?ChequeAccountNo -15- Left justified, space padded?>
                <xsl:call-template name="reformat-string-length">
                      <xsl:with-param name="value" select="ChequeAccNo"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="str-len" select="15"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>                    
                <?ChequeNo - 6 - Right justified, zero padded?>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(ChequeNo, '000000')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
                <?BankBranchCode - 6 - space padded?>
                <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
                <?ChequeAccountNo -15- Left justified, space padded?>
                <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
                <?ChequeNo - 6 - Right justified, zero padded?>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(0, '000000')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <?PayAmountCents - 9 - Right justified, zero padded?>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Amount, '000000000')"/>
        <?PaymentDateTime (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)?>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Date,8,4)"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-month-3letter-to-number">
            <xsl:with-param name="month-3letter" select="substring(Date,4,3)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Date,1,2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Time,1,2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Time,4,2)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(Time,7,2)"/>
        <?Entry Mode?>
        <xsl:text>M</xsl:text>
        <?AmountSign - 1- ?>
        <xsl:text>D</xsl:text>
        <?Filler?>
        <xsl:call-template name="pad-some-space">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentlength" select="1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="newlength" select="77"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <?Line?>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <?Body Ends?>
    <?Trailer Starts?>
    <?RECORDTYPE?>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <?COMPANYCODE?>
    <xsl:text>WHK</xsl:text>
    <?PAYMENTBATCHNO?>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(user:GetBatchNo('Batchcow','C:\WebRiposte\Agents\Configuration\Configurations.xml'),'000000')"/>
    <?TOTALAMOUNTCENTS?>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//Amount), '00000000000')"/>
    <?AMOUNTSIGN?>
    <xsl:text>D</xsl:text>
    <?FILLER?>
    <xsl:call-template name="pad-some-space">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentlength" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="newlength" select="235"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <?Trailer Ends?>
</xsl:template>
<?Support functions ------------------- ?>
<?Date time format?>
<xsl:template name="format-date-time">
    <xsl:param name="currdatetime"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($currdatetime,1,4),substring($currdatetime,6,2),substring($currdatetime,9,2),substring($currdatetime,12,2),substring($currdatetime,15,2),substring($currdatetime,18,2))"/>
</xsl:template>
<?Convert month from text to number?>
<xsl:template name="format-month-3letter-to-number">
    <xsl:param name="month-3letter"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MonthName" select="'Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(substring-after($MonthName,$month-3letter),'00'),1,2)"/>
</xsl:template>
<?Pad space?>
<xsl:template name="pad-some-space">
    <xsl:param name="currentlength"/>
    <xsl:param name="newlength"/>
    <xsl:if test="number($currentlength) &lt; number($newlength)">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="pad-some-space">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentlength" select="number($currentlength)+1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="newlength" select="$newlength"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<?Evaluate-string-length?>
<xsl:template name="reformat-string-length">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="str-len"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($value) &gt; number($str-len)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($value,1,$str-len)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="pad-some-space">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentlength" select="string-length($value)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="newlength" select="number($str-len)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem (and make your code readable while at it)? Make sure to include an example input XML, too. -- As an aside: XSLT processes (e.g. counts) the input XML, not the output tree.

Comment: @Michael, I refer to the following in the XSLT code: <?NUMRECORDS?>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//SessionId),'000000')"/>

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have the time to edit your code. Please post something that can be copied, pasted and run to show the problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to format the XML sample, but having done so, I can see there is are no `SessionId` elements present in it at all, so it is not clear what you are trying to count. Perhaps you mean to do `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//GroupId),'000000')"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying problems is always good. Although it involved some guess work, I simplified your problem to this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="original" match="/XML/Record" use="TxnId"/>
  <xsl:key name="copy" match="/XML/Record" use="OrigTxnId"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//GroupId),'000000')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="XML/Record[not(key('original', OrigTxnId) or key('copy', TxnId))]">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Account, '00000000000000000000')"/>
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note, as mentioned in my comments, I have replaced `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//Session),'000000')"/>` with `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//GroupId),'000000')"/>`)

This outputs the following

```
000005
00000000000012440531
00000000000010895388
00000000000010605762
```

So, the first count says 5 items, but there are only 3 rows.

Now, in your code, you have this `xsl:for-each`

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="XML/Record[not(key('original', OrigTxnId) or key('copy', TxnId))]">
```

So, all you need to do is add the condition in you `xsl:for-each` to your count statement.

```
 <xsl:value-of 
      select="format-number(count(XML/Record[not(key('original', OrigTxnId) or key('copy', TxnId))]/GroupId),'000000')"/>
```

It might be better to make use of a variable to remove the repetitive coding.

As an example, try this XSLT as a basis

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="original" match="/XML/Record" use="TxnId"/>
  <xsl:key name="copy" match="/XML/Record" use="OrigTxnId"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="records" select="XML/Record[not(key('original', OrigTxnId) or key('copy', TxnId))]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count($records/GroupId),'000000')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$records">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Account, '00000000000000000000')"/>
     <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This outputs the following:

```
000003
00000000000012440531
00000000000010895388
00000000000010605762
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Final question, In the Body, I have the following:

Comment: <?SeqNo - 6 - Right justified, zero padded?>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(preceding-sibling::Record)+1, '000000')"/>

Comment: The count is not sequential. It still take in consideration the record removed.